# What is the difference between isset($var) == "Test" and isset($var) && $var == 'Test"

Tags: php, isset

What is the difference between `isset($var) == "Test"` and `isset($var) && $var == 'Test"`?

Comment: isset($var) checks whether $var is initailized or no. and isset($var) == "Test" checks whether the initialized variable is equal to Test. Both the above provide you same result

Comment: If only there was some kind of....document that described how functions like `isset()` worked and what they returned...

Comment: To be accurate actually `isset($var) == "Test"` evaluates the boolean return value of `isset` against the string 'test';

Comment: I would not down vote this question as it quiete clear what the asker is confused about. Helping ninjascorner is more appropriate then downvoting a starting programmer, thats my opinion.

Comment: Thanks guys...I was so confused as one of my co-developer is using this all the time and I keep arguing with him but I have no proof as I am a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a short example:

```
$var = "Chuck Test";

var_dump(isset($var)); // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($undefined)); // bool(false)

var_dump(isset($var) == "Chuck Test"); // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($var) && $var == "Chuck Test"); // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($undefined) == "Chuck Test"); // bool(false)
var_dump(isset($undefined) && $undefined == "Chuck Test"); // bool(false)
```

it looks like they are equivalent but they aren't:

```
var_dump(isset($var) == "Chuck Testa"); // bool(true) !!!
var_dump(isset($var) && $var == "Chuck Testa"); // bool(false)
```

because isset() returns `true` or `false`, and an non-empty string compared to `true` results in `true`.

So better use the `isset($var) && $var == "Test"` variant, because it does what you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

The first one makes no sense.  As you can see [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns a Boolean.  So `isset($var) == "Test"` as I said evaluates a bool against a string.

With the evaluation `isset($var) && $var == 'Test'` PHP first checks if the variable $var is defined and then if that value is equal to the string 'test'.

Calling just `$var == 'Test` without ensuring that it is set will result in an 'Undefined variable' notice.  If you are not sure and don't want a noisy log then you can check with isset.

Comment: IMO Code which generates a ton of unnecessary notices smells bad. It's good practice to check a if a variable/array index is defined before you use it.

Comment: Strings have boolean values in PHP.

Comment: @JackManey, Not sure I understand what you are trying to say.  Yes, anything may be cast as a Boolean.  `var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)`,  Only the following strings will resolve to *false*, *the empty string, and the string "0"*

Answer (score 1):

The function `isset()` returns true (boolean) if a variable is set. Now when you compare a boolean == "Test", it is bogus. So to check whether your variable is set and has the value of 'Test' you should use `isset($var) && $var == 'Test'`. But I don't see why you should not do `$var == 'Test'. Does the interpreter complain about uninitialized variable that way?

Read the following, ask any question if you do not understand what the function `isset` actually does:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: PHP complains if you use a variable or an array index which has not yet been defined, unless you pass it to functions like `empty` or `isset` to check wheter they are defined.